# Maxmind DB convert ASN to IP

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, geoip, maxmind, geoip2

The Maxmind ASN Database can be used in python geoip2 to convert IP to ASN and ASN name. Similarly, how to get IP range(s) from AS number?

Answer (score 0):

You just need an ASN database.

You can sign up one free database from IP2Location LITE.

http://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-asn

Then you have all the ranges of IP address by ASN.